# Unable to use submodule dependency class in test, throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, multi-module, maven-module

I am working on a maven multi-module project with the following structure

```
project/
├── migration/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── main/
│   │   │   └── Migration.java
│   │   └── test
│   └── pom.xml
├── depends-on-migration/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── main (uses Migration.java - ok)
│   │   └── test (uses Migration.java - throws NoClassDefFoundError)
│   └── pom.xml (depends on migration)
└── pom.xml
```

The class can be used (see image), but cannot compile when I run `mvnw package` (see logs)

[image]

```
2022-12-17T14:22:56.025+08:00  INFO 13468 --- [           main] c.b.d.DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests : Starting DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests using Java 17.0.2 with PID 13468 (started by Joseph in Z:\bwgjoseph\maven-nested-multi-module-project\depends-on-migration)
2022-12-17T14:22:56.031+08:00  INFO 13468 --- [           main] c.b.d.DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-17T14:22:57.289+08:00  INFO 13468 --- [           main] c.b.d.DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests : Started DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests in 1.534 seconds (process running for 2.498)
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.493 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.bwgjoseph.dependsonmigration.DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests
[ERROR] test1  Time elapsed: 0.454 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/bwgjoseph/migration/Migration
        at com.bwgjoseph.dependsonmigration.DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests.test1(DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bwgjoseph.migration.Migration
        at com.bwgjoseph.dependsonmigration.DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests.test1(DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests.java:17)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   DependsOnMigrationApplicationTests.test1:17 NoClassDefFound com/bwgjoseph/migr...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

This is a simplified example, can refer to [repo](https://github.com/bwgjoseph/maven-nested-multi-module-project) (migration and depends-on-migration module)

I couldn't find anything similar, the closest I could find are cases where they are looking to use classes that are defined in `migration/src/test` but I am using `migration/src/main`

Glad to provide more information if required.

Thanks!

Comment: Running the test itself is fine. Try running `mvnw package` at the project root. And yes, I ran on command line and it is throwing the said error

Comment: Which of the modules should be deployable spring boot application?

Comment: Would it matter? This is a sample project, but if it matters, then can assume that `depends-on-migration` is the deployable one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in both `migration` and `depends-on-migration` modules.

Spring Boot Maven Plugin produces an Uber-Jar, with a layout expected by Spring apps. The original jar (without dependencies) is renamed to `migration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original`

The structure of uber-jar

```
.
├── BOOT-INF
│   ├── classes
│   ├── classpath.idx
│   ├── layers.idx
│   └── lib
├── META-INF
├── migration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
└── org
    └── springframework
```

Your code is placed in `BOOT-INF/classes` - this is not a typical library layout, hence `ClassNotFoundException`.

See [The Executable Jar Format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) for reference.

If you remove `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in migration project, `mvn package` passes.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense, but what if my `migration` project is a `spring-boot` application and requires `spring-boot-maven-plugin`? Is there any way around it?

Comment: You can configure spring-boot-maven-plugin to produce original jar with a name that can be imported via classifier. See [Using a Spring Boot Application as a Dependency](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency)

Comment: nice! I think that should work nicely. If I get that right, is to create two separate jar, one for boot application, another as dependency.

Comment: Do not create the überjar until you create your deployment.  This should be elsewhere.